# Show that an element belongs to unique factorization domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let D be a UFD with quotient field F. If f (x) $\in$ D[x] is monic and b$\in$ F such that f (b) = 0 , then show that b$\in$ D.

All I know is

F is a field and f(b) = 0 therefore $$f(x) = (x-b)q(x)$$ and also f(x) $\in$ D[x] so f(x) can be written as the product of some irreducible elements of D[x].

What should I do to show that b$\in$ D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\: $ Mimic the proof of the [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) which works over any domain where gcds exist, i.e $\rm\:(a,b) = 1,\ 0 = b^n\:\! f(a/b) =\: a^n + b\:(\cdots)\ \Rightarrow\ b\:|\:a^n\ \Rightarrow\ b\:|\:1\:$ by Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: If you're looking for a bigger hammer, the name Eisenstein might help.

Comment: @Chris How do you propose to use Eisenstein generally?

Comment: Scrap that. I thought I had learned Eisenstein for UFDs, but cannot find a reference to back that up right now, so my memory is probably faulty.

Comment: @Chris It does work over UFDs, but how do you propose to apply it here?

Comment: Gauss' lemma, which follows from Eisenstein, implies that if a monic polynomial over a UFD $D$ has a zero over the quotient field of $D$, then that zero is an element of $D$, no? (I agree, a pointer to Gauss' lemma would have been more appropriate.)

Comment: @Chris How do you propose to prove Gauss' Lemma from Eisenstein's?

Comment: Too true, my memory was faulty. The order of proofs is exactly the other way round (and it seems that Gauss' Lemma is around 45 years older).