# Some localization is not finitely-generated as an R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain with field of fractions $K$, and let $f \in R$ be a non-zero non-unit.
Prove that the subring $S=R[1/f]$ of $K$ is not finitely-generated as an $R$-module, using the fact that every element of $S$ may be written in the form $r/f^n$ with $r\in R$ and $n\geq0$, and any finite set of elements of $S$ can be written like this with a common denominator.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy Answer: $fx-1$ is not monic. Edit: This is wrong unless $R$ is integrally closed.

Hard Answer: Suppose $S=R[1/f]$ is finitely generated and let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be a generating set of $S$. By the fact we're allowed to use we may write the generators as $r_1/f^{e_1},\dots, r_n/f^{e_n}$. Let $e=e_1\dots e_n $ and write $1/f^{e+1}$ with respect to this generating set,

$$\frac{1}{f^{e+1}}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i r_i}{f^{e_i}}$$

for some $b_i \in R$. Multiplying by $f^e$ we deduce that $1/f \in R$ and so $f$ is a unit which is a contradiction.

Comment: It's not clear what proof the "easy answer" denotes. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @MathGems In an extension of rings $R \subset S$ an element $\alpha \in S$ is integral over $R$ if it satisfies a monic polynomial over $R$, in particular if its minimum polynomial over $R$ is monic. We have the very nice equivalence $\alpha$ is integral over $R$ if and only if $R[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

Comment: But if $R$ is not *integrally closed,* then minimal polynomials of elements integral over $R$ need not be monic, e.g. the minimal polynomial of $\zeta_3$ over $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]\,$ is $\rm\:2\, x+1\! +\!\sqrt{-3}\ \ $

Comment: @MathGems, Good point I get too comfortable working over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @YACP It was a tongue-in-cheek comment in contrast to my original one-line solution, which of course turned out to be wrong in general.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K$ be the quotient field of $A$. Let be a subring of $K$ containing $A$ and $f^{-1}$.

We have to show that $A[f^{-1}]$ is not finitely generated.

On contrary, suppose $A[f^{-1}]$ is finitely generated. Then $f^{-1}$ is integral over $A$ by proposition of the book Commutative Algebra by Atiyah. $i.e.,$ there are $a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{n}\in A$ such that \begin{equation}
f^{-n}+ a_{n}f^{-(n-1)}+...+ a_{1}=0
\end{equation}
By multiplying with $f^{n}$, we have 
\begin{equation}
1+ a_{n}f+...+ a_{1}f^{n}=0
\end{equation}
$i.e.,$ \begin{equation}
-f(a_{n}+...+a_{1}f^{n-1})=1
\end{equation}
Thus $f$ is a unit that yield a contradiction of the hypothesis.

Comment: Which "proposition of the book Commutative Algebra by Atiyah"?

Comment: @user26857 Proposition 5.1 of the book Commutative Algebra by Atiyah.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $  One conceptual way to view this is as a generalization of the familiar case when $\rm\,R = \Bbb Z,\,$ where the Rational Root Test implies that *proper* fractions cannot be roots of polynomials $\rm\in \Bbb Z[x]\,$ that are *monic* (i.e. leading coefficient $= 1).$

Let $\rm\,e = 1/f.\:$ If $\rm\:R[e] = R\left<1,e,\ldots,e^n\right>\,$ then $\rm\,e^{n+1}$ is an $\rm\,R$-linear combination of lower powers of $\rm\,e,\,$ i.e. the proper fraction $\rm\,e\,$ is a root of a *monic* polynomial over $\rm\,R.\,$ Therefore the  [proof of the Rational Root Test (RRT)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/129764/23500) shows that the denominator $\rm\,f\,$ divides the leading coefficient $ = 1,\, $ i.e. $\rm\,1/f\in R,\,$  contra hypothesis.

**Remark** $\ $ The RRT requires that the fraction be in lowest terms, i.e. that the denominator and numerator are coprime, which is true here since the numerator $= 1$.

A domain $\rm\,D\,$ is called *integrally closed* (in its fraction field) if none of its proper fractions are integral over $\rm\,D,\,$  i.e. they are not roots of monic polynomials over $\rm\,D.\:$ The usual proof of the Rational Root Test works in any domain where gcds exist (gcd-domain), e.g. in any UFD. Therefore gcd-domains and UFDs are integrally-closed.